# What is full form of r and K in r-selection species and K-selection species?

Tags: ecology, terminology, population-dynamics

What is full form/ meaning of 'r' and 'K' in [r-selection species and K-selection species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R/K_selection_theory)? Does this 'r' means "Random" and the 'K' means "constant"?

Comment: [This is from Wikipedia (with no other references): "In the etymology of the Verhulst equation, r comes from rate while K comes from carrying capacity. In German, the word for capacity is Kapazität and K stands for the "Kapazitätsgrenze" (capacity limit)."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R/K_selection_theory#Overview) I haven't been able to find the first paper defining them, which is apparently from the early 19th century.

Comment: If anyone can find this paper, the answer *may* be inside: Verhulst. 1838. notice sur la loi que la poulation pursuit dans son accroissement

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by full form. The wikipedia article you cited defines r and k selection and also describes which each variable means in the Verhulst equation. Could you clarify exactly what you're confused about?

Comment: Not the real answer but a good mental handle -
r is rabbits' strategy, K is Kangaroos'.

Comment: @gill-gabel we were taught to remember it as r = "rapid" and K = "Kautious" :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/275142242_R-Selection_and_K-Selection) article discusses the origin of the terms. They come directly from the equation used to describe population dynamics. As Canadianer mentioned the Wiki also covers it quite well.

"r" stands for "rate" {growth rate}, r strategists have a high r value and a low K value. They grow fast but most die.

"K" stands for Kapazitätsgrenzen which is german for capacity limit, now called carrying capacity, K strategists have a low r and a high K. They grow slow but more survive.

[image]

Comment: @Canadianer Thanks for catching that I meant to reverse the terms and then forgot to go back and do it when I started trying to get an equation to import.

Comment: That should be *Kapazitätsgren**ze***. "Grenze" is the German word for limit/border.

Comment: Correctly answers my question, and accepted using green tick mark.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to understand and remember these letters, because I too found these terms confusing initially, then I use the following.

r-strategy = focus is on Reproduction Rate as much as possible - then all the other traits, grow fast, die young, etc, tend to follow.

K-strategy = focus is on the Kapacity (Germanised spelling) of the environment, i.e. do not exceed the carrying capacity of the local environment for your species.

Comment: The question is about the origin of these terms. Your answer doesn't seem to address that.

Comment: Upvoted since it may indicate possible etymology but op wasnt finding mnemonic rather op was misleaded where somehow a mnemonic was misinterpreted as a techinical. definition.

Comment: WYSIWYG: The questioner was asking about the etymology, but I think not out of interest in linguistics, but out of a need to (1) understand and (2) remember these terms. When the letter cannot be related to a word (in a language you know), this becomes difficult in both respects. So my response answers the implied need. In any case, my response also contains some etymology. Obviously, making the word Kapacity tells you that this letter comes from the German for Capacity. And R standing for Reproduction Rate surely tells you that that is the etymology/source of the user of that letter?